# make: dh: Command not found

Tags: compiling, dh-make

When I try to run the .run file on nautilus the pointer changes into a wheel and does nothing, I did change the permission to make it executable, also at first it only tryed to open it with gedit so I had to manually choose to execute it as a program from the menu. After I run it on terminal and try to build the package for later install it gives me this error and I can't figure out what's the issue.

```
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
make: *** [build-arch] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
Cleaning in directory .
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: debhelper (>= 7) dh-modaliases execstack
debuild: fatal error at line 1328:
You do not appear to have all build dependencies properly met.
You can use mk-build-deps to generate a dummy package which
Depends on all the required packages, or you can install them
manually using dpkg or apt using the error messages just above
this message.
```

On IRC someone told me it could be devscripts but after installing it still gave me the error so I uninstalled it again. I'm trying to install this because the one in ubuntu fglrx-updates won't let me open amdccl as administrator, a little black window opens requesting the password but it won't do anything after and it closes too fast to see any message. Any ideas?

By the way I also used this command `sudo sh *.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty` but I think I got the same error as well. Dang, I checked the ati site http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/amdcatalyst13-12linreleasenotes.aspx it seems like the driver is not compatible with 14.04 or kernel 3.13 but I'm just trying to build the package not install it, it should at least do that right? I still would like to fix the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The guy in IRC was almost there, but not quite. The package that you need is called `dh-make` no `devscripts`. A simple `sudo apt-get install dh-make` should fix the issue.

How to know:

```
chmod 744 debian/pxpress/switch*
dh build
make: dh: Command not found
make: *** [build-arch] Error 127
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
```

`dh build` starts creating a debian package with the debhelper scripts, all these scripts are appended with the `dh_` string. In this case, `dh` called a helper called `dh_make` to build the debian package.

Another cue you have is this line:

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: debhelper (>= 7) dh-modaliases execstack
```

You need debhelper, dh-modaliases and execstack to build the package. debhelper suggests dh-make, and suggestions are normally installed.

Comment: I installed almost all of debhelper and execstack and it build the package, thanks for the help, gonna install ubuntu-dev-tool anyways and in the ati site it seems ubuntu 14.04 is not compatible so I'm going to hold on installing it. Any ideas why it won't run .run or files without extension on nautilus?

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Install your driver though  Software center.

> Ubuntu software center > Edit menu > Software sources > Additional Drivers

## OR

run these commands in your Terminal:

> sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
> sudo apt-get install fglrx

Then you will be able to use Catalyst Control Center.

Comment: I have already done that but it won't let me open amd ccl as administrator. Also it doesn't look that good http://goo.gl/uE54Cn

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: I already had build-essential installed so that doesn't seem to be the issue, as for using fglrx that would be the same as changing the option from the sofware center, I used fglrx-updates which is the latest and I want to use the latest stable version of the ati site.